# Why does multiplying by a rotation matrix change the eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It seems that when I multiply a matrix by a rotation (orthogonal) matrix, the eigen values change. This is counter-intuitive to me since multiplying by a rotation matrix is simply expressing the column vectors in a new coordinate system. Also, aren't eigen values supposed to be properties of the vector space, supposedly independent of the chosen basis? Can someone provide an intuitive explanation for why the eigen values change?

EDIT: This is what I meant when I said a rotation matrix expresses a vector it is multiplied by in a new coordinate system:

```
import numpy as np
theta=np.pi/4
rot=np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]]) 
## Expresses the vector [1,-1] in the coordinate system rotated by 45 degrees
np.dot(rot,np.array([1,-1]))
## Result is [1.414,0]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the degrees by which a rotation matrix rotates and compared that to the degrees between the new eigen vectors and the old one? Or even simpler, multiply the old eigen vectors by the rotation matrix and check that you get the current eigen vectors?

Comment: The eigen vectors will change no doubt. But it seems to me the eigen values shouldn't (though obviously they do).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g best explanation there is.

Comment: *"...multiplying by a rotation matrix is simply expressing the column vectors in a new coordinate system"*. No, it isn't. Change of coordinate system for a linear map is realised by similarity transforms, not by multiplication of a single rotation matrix.

Comment: To @user1551 point: the change of co-ordinate matrix requires multiplication by a matrix on the left and its inverse on the right. So rotation is not quite the same as "changing basis"....I mean, you are rotating everything, and although rotation is isometric, it is not changing bases.

Comment: @ReverseFlow: See my edit.

Comment: Well, no. That coordinate system is same as the original one...you just rotated a vector in the same space as you had before. It jist moved to a new place in the same system. Multiply it on the right by the inverse of your matrix and then we are talking new basis/coordinate system.

Comment: Consider the simplest possible example: let $I$ be the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Obviously it has eigenvalue $1$ (with multiplicity $2$). Let $R$ be some arbitrary rotation matrix. Multiply it by $I$ (on either side) and what do you get? $RI = IR = R$. In general $R$ doesn't have any real eigenvalues. So, eigenvalues are not preserved even in this simplest case. The answer to this conundrum is that for an arbitrary matrix $A$, the product $RA$ is not expressing $A$ in different coordinates. For that you need $RAR^{-1}$. (For a rotation matrix, this is equivalent to $RAR^T$.)

Comment: @Bugo Let $R$ be a rotation matrix that rotates by 45 degrees ($[[0.707,-0.707],[0.707,0.707]]$). Consider a matrix, $A=[[1,1],[-1,1]]$. Then, $R^T A R = A$. It doesn't seem to have expressed it in a different system.

Comment: What makes you think that the matrices of a linear transformation with respect to different bases are necessarily unequal? The identity map, for instance, has the same matrix in _every_ basis.

Comment: @RohitPandey That's because your specific choice of $A$ is just a rotation matrix times a scalar, namely $$A = \sqrt{2}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\pi/4) & \sin(\pi/4) \\ -\sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4)\end{pmatrix}$$ And all $2 \times 2$ rotations commute. (This is not true in higher dimensions.) So in your example, $R^TAR = R^T R A = A$ since $RR^T = I$. If you try a more general matrix $A$ you will see $R^T A R \neq A$ in general.

Comment: @bugo This is where I'm coming from: Let's take a vector [1,1]. Clearly if you express it in the coordinate system which is rotated with respect to the current one by 45 degrees, all the mass should shift to one of the dimensions with the other becoming zero. So, multiplying that vector with $R$ does indeed give you a result that has all its mass in one  of the dimensions. No where in this example, did I multiply by $R^T$. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you keep misspelling @Bungo 's name?

Comment: @RohitPandey Vectors and matrices are different objects. Yes, changing the basis of a vector $v$ is equivalent to multiplying by an invertible matrix $B$ to get $Bv$. If you want to represent a matrix $A$ in the same coordinates, think of it as three steps: first convert the input vector $v$ to the new coordinates, resulting in $Bv$. Now apply a matrix $M$ (which we'll identify in a moment), yielding $MBv$. Then convert back to the original coordinates: $B^{-1}MBv$. We want this to equal $Av$, for all $v$, hence we want $B^{-1}MB = A$. Thus $M = BAB^{-1}$ represents $A$ in the new coordinates.